# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null (Javascript/Wordpress)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to get a plug-in called [Appointment calendar](http://wordpress.dwbooster.com/calendars/cp-appointment-calendar#download) to work with my wordpress website, but the calendar supposed to appear doesn't. The reported error is

> File: jquery.cycle.all.min.js
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
>   [cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1

Here is the referred line:

```
``(function($){var ver="2.99";if($.support==undefined){$.support={opacity:!($.browser.msie)};}function debug(s){$.fn.cycle.debug&&log(s);}function log(){window.console&&console.log&&console.log("[cycle] "+Array.prototype.join.call(arguments," "));}$.expr[":"].paused=function(el){return el.cyclePause;};$.fn.cycle=function(options,arg2){var o={s:this.selector,c:this.context};if(this.length===0&&options!="stop"){if(!$.isReady&&o.s){log("DOM not ready, queuing slideshow");$(function(){$(o.s,o.c).cycle(options,arg2);});return this;}log("terminating; zero elements found by selector"+($.isReady?"":" (DOM not ready)"));return this;}return this.each(function(){var opts=handleArguments(this,options,arg2);if(opts===false){return;}opts.updateActivePagerLink=opts.updateActivePagerLink||$.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink;if(this.cycleTimeout){clearTimeout(this.cycleTimeout);}this.cycleTimeout=this.cyclePause=0;var $cont=$(this);var $slides=opts.slideExpr?$(opts.slideExpr,this):$cont.children();var els=$slides.get();if(els.length<2){log("terminating; too few slides: "+els.length);return;}var opts2=buildOptions($cont,$slides,els,opts,o);if(opts2===false){return;}var startTime=opts2.continuous?10:getTimeout(els[opts2.currSlide],els[opts2.nextSlide],opts2,!opts2.backwards);if(startTime){startTime+=(opts2.delay||0);if(startTime<10){startTime=10;}debug("first timeout: "+startTime);this.cycleTimeout=setTimeout(function(){go(els,opts2,0,!opts.backwards);},startTime);}});};function handleArguments(cont,options,arg2){if(cont.cycleStop==undefined){cont.cycleStop=0;}if(options===undefined||options===null){options={};}if(options.constructor==String){switch(options){case"destroy":case"stop":var opts=$(cont).data("cycle.opts");if(!opts){return false;}cont.cycleStop++;if(cont.cycleTimeout){clearTimeout(cont.cycleTimeout);}cont.cycleTimeout=0;$(cont).removeData("cycle.opts");if(options=="destroy"){destroy(opts);}return false;case"toggle":cont.cyclePause=(cont.cyclePause===1)?0:1;checkInstantResume(cont.cyclePause,arg2,cont);return false;case"pause":cont.cyclePause=1;return false;case"resume":cont.cyclePause=0;checkInstantResume(false,arg2,cont);return false;case"prev":case"next":var opts=$(cont).data("cycle.opts");if(!opts){log('options not found, "prev/next" ignored');return false;}$.fn.cycle[options](opts);return false;default:options={fx:options};}return options;}else{if(options.constructor==Number){var num=options;options=$(cont).data("cycle.opts");if(!options){log("options not found, can not advance slide");return false;}if(num<0||num>=options.elements.length){log("invalid slide index: "+num);return false;}options.nextSlide=num;if(cont.cycleTimeout){clearTimeout(cont.cycleTimeout);cont.cycleTimeout=0;}if(typeof arg2=="string"){options.oneTimeFx=arg2;}go(options.elements,options,1,num>=options.currSlide);return false;}}return options;function checkInstantResume(isPaused,arg2,cont){if(!isPaused&&arg2===true){var options=$(cont).data("cycle.opts");if(!options){log("options not found, can not resume");return false;}if(cont.cycleTimeout){clearTimeout(cont.cycleTimeout);cont.cycleTimeout=0;}go(options.elements,options,1,!options.backwards);}}}function removeFilter(el,opts){if(!$.support.opacity&&opts.cleartype&&el.style.filter){try{el.style.removeAttribute("filter");}catch(smother){}}}function destroy(opts){if(opts.next){$(opts.next).unbind(opts.prevNextEvent);}if(opts.prev){$(opts.prev).unbind(opts.prevNextEvent);}if(opts.pager||opts.pagerAnchorBuilder){$.each(opts.pagerAnchors||[],function(){this.unbind().remove();});}opts.pagerAnchors=null;if(opts.destroy){opts.destroy(opts);}}function buildOptions($cont,$slides,els,options,o){var opts=$.extend({},$.fn.cycle.defaults,options||{},$.metadata?$cont.metadata():$.meta?$cont.data():{});if(opts.autostop){opts.countdown=opts.autostopCount||els.length;}var cont=$cont[0];$cont.data("cycle.opts",opts);opts.$cont=$cont;opts.stopCount=cont.cycleStop;opts.elements=els;opts.before=opts.before?[opts.before]:[];opts.after=opts.after?[opts.after]:[];if(!$.support.opacity&&opts.cleartype){opts.after.push(function(){removeFilter(this,opts);});}if(opts.continuous){opts.after.push(function(){go(els,opts,0,!opts.backwards);});}saveOriginalOpts(opts);if(!$.support.opacity&&opts.cleartype&&!opts.cleartypeNoBg){clearTypeFix($slides);}if($cont.css("position")=="static"){$cont.css("position","relative");}if(opts.width){$cont.width(opts.width);}if(opts.height&&opts.height!="auto"){$cont.height(opts.height);}if(opts.startingSlide){opts.startingSlide=parseInt(opts.startingSlide);}else{if(opts.backwards){opts.startingSlide=els.length-1;}}if(opts.random){opts.randomMap=[];for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){opts.randomMap.push(i);}opts.randomMap.sort(function(a,b){return Math.random()-0.5;});opts.randomIndex=1;opts.startingSlide=opts.randomMap[1];}else{if(opts.startingSlide>=els.length){opts.startingSlide=0;}}opts.currSlide=opts.startingSlide||0;var first=opts.startingSlide;$slides.css({position:"absolute",top:0,left:0}).hide().each(function(i){var z;if(opts.backwards){z=first?i<=first?els.length+(i-first):first-i:els.length-i;}else{z=first?i>=first?els.length-(i-first):first-i:els.length-i;}$(this).css("z-index",z);});$(els[first]).css("opacity",1).show();removeFilter(els[first],opts);if(opts.fit&&opts.width){$slides.width(opts.width);}if(opts.fit&&opts.height&&opts.height!="auto"){$slides.height(opts.height);}var reshape=opts.containerResize&&!$cont.innerHeight();if(reshape){var maxw=0,maxh=0;for(var j=0;j<els.length;j++){var $e=$(els[j]),e=$e[0],w=$e.outerWidth(),h=$e.outerHeight();if(!w){w=e.offsetWidth||e.width||$e.attr("width");}if(!h){h=e.offsetHeight||e.height||$e.attr("height");}maxw=w>maxw?w:maxw;maxh=h>maxh?h:maxh;}if(maxw>0&&maxh>0){$cont.css({width:maxw+"px",height:maxh+"px"});}}if(opts.pause){$cont.hover(function(){this.cyclePause++;},function(){this.cyclePause--;});}if(supportMultiTransitions(opts)===false){return false;}var requeue=false;options.requeueAttempts=options.requeueAttempts||0;$slides.each(function(){var $el=$(this);this.cycleH=(opts.fit&&opts.height)?opts.height:($el.height()||this.offsetHeight||this.height||$el.attr("height")||0);this.cycleW=(opts.fit&&opts.width)?opts.width:($el.width()||this.offsetWidth||this.width||$el.attr("width")||0);if($el.is("img")){var loadingIE=($.browser.msie&&this.cycleW==28&&this.cycleH==30&&!this.complete);var loadingFF=($.browser.mozilla&&this.cycleW==34&&this.cycleH==19&&!this.complete);var loadingOp=($.browser.opera&&((this.cycleW==42&&this.cycleH==19)||(this.cycleW==37&&this.cycleH==17))&&!this.complete);var loadingOther=(this.cycleH==0&&this.cycleW==0&&!this.complete);if(loadingIE||loadingFF||loadingOp||loadingOther){if(o.s&&opts.requeueOnImageNotLoaded&&++options.requeueAttempts<100){log(options.requeueAttempts," - img slide not loaded, requeuing slideshow: ",this.src,this.cycleW,this.cycleH);setTimeout(function(){$(o.s,o.c).cycle(options);},opts.requeueTimeout);requeue=true;return false;}else{log("could not determine size of image: "+this.src,this.cycleW,this.cycleH);}}}return true;});if(requeue){return false;}opts.cssBefore=opts.cssBefore||{};opts.cssAfter=opts.cssAfter||{};opts.cssFirst=opts.cssFirst||{};opts.animIn=opts.animIn||{};opts.animOut=opts.animOut||{};$slides.not(":eq("+first+")").css(opts.cssBefore);$($slides[first]).css(opts.cssFirst);if(opts.timeout){opts.timeout=parseInt(opts.timeout);if(opts.speed.constructor==String){opts.speed=$.fx.speeds[opts.speed]||parseInt(opts.speed);}if(!opts.sync){opts.speed=opts.speed/2;}var buffer=opts.fx=="none"?0:opts.fx=="shuffle"?500:250;while((opts.timeout-opts.speed)<buffer){opts.timeout+=opts.speed;}}if(opts.easing){opts.easeIn=opts.easeOut=opts.easing;}if(!opts.speedIn){opts.speedIn=opts.speed;}if(!opts.speedOut){opts.speedOut=opts.speed;}opts.slideCount=els.length;opts.currSlide=opts.lastSlide=first;if(opts.random){if(++opts.randomIndex==els.length){opts.randomIndex=0;}opts.nextSlide=opts.randomMap[opts.randomIndex];}else{if(opts.backwards){opts.nextSlide=opts.startingSlide==0?(els.length-1):opts.startingSlide-1;}else{opts.nextSlide=opts.startingSlide>=(els.length-1)?0:opts.startingSlide+1;}}if(!opts.multiFx){var init=$.fn.cycle.transitions[opts.fx];if($.isFunction(init)){init($cont,$slides,opts);}else{if(opts.fx!="custom"&&!opts.multiFx){log("unknown transition: "+opts.fx,"; slideshow terminating");return false;}}}var e0=$slides[first];if(opts.before.length){opts.before[0].apply(e0,[e0,e0,opts,true]);}if(opts.after.length){opts.after[0].apply(e0,[e0,e0,opts,true]);}if(opts.next){$(opts.next).bind(opts.prevNextEvent,function(){return advance(opts,1);});}if(opts.prev){$(opts.prev).bind(opts.prevNextEvent,function(){return advance(opts,0);});}if(opts.pager||opts.pagerAnchorBuilder){buildPager(els,opts);}exposeAddSlide(opts,els);return opts;}function saveOriginalOpts(opts){opts.original={before:[],after:[]};opts.original.cssBefore=$.extend({},opts.cssBefore);opts.original.cssAfter=$.extend({},opts.cssAfter);opts.original.animIn=$.extend({},opts.animIn);opts.original.animOut=$.extend({},opts.animOut);$.each(opts.before,function(){opts.original.before.push(this);});$.each(opts.after,function(){opts.original.after.push(this);});}function supportMultiTransitions(opts){var i,tx,txs=$.fn.cycle.transitions;if(opts.fx.indexOf(",")>0){opts.multiFx=true;opts.fxs=opts.fx.replace(/\s*/g,"").split(",");for(i=0;i<opts.fxs.length;i++){var fx=opts.fxs[i];tx=txs[fx];if(!tx||!txs.hasOwnProperty(fx)||!$.isFunction(tx)){log("discarding unknown transition: ",fx);opts.fxs.splice(i,1);i--;}}if(!opts.fxs.length){log("No valid transitions named; slideshow terminating.");return false;}}else{if(opts.fx=="all"){opts.multiFx=true;opts.fxs=[];for(p in txs){tx=txs[p];if(txs.hasOwnProperty(p)&&$.isFunction(tx)){opts.fxs.push(p);}}}}if(opts.multiFx&&opts.randomizeEffects){var r1=Math.floor(Math.random()*20)+30;for(i=0;i<r1;i++){var r2=Math.floor(Math.random()*opts.fxs.length);opts.fxs.push(opts.fxs.splice(r2,1)[0]);}debug("randomized fx sequence: ",opts.fxs);}return true;}function exposeAddSlide(opts,els){opts.addSlide=function(newSlide,prepend){var $s=$(newSlide),s=$s[0];if(!opts.autostopCount){opts.countdown++;}els[prepend?"unshift":"push"](s);if(opts.els){opts.els[prepend?"unshift":"push"](s);}opts.slideCount=els.length;$s.css("position","absolute");$s[prepend?"prependTo":"appendTo"](opts.$cont);if(prepend){opts.currSlide++;opts.nextSlide++;}if(!$.support.opacity&&opts.cleartype&&!opts.cleartypeNoBg){clearTypeFix($s);}if(opts.fit&&opts.width){$s.width(opts.width);}if(opts.fit&&opts.height&&opts.height!="auto"){$s.height(opts.height);}s.cycleH=(opts.fit&&opts.height)?opts.height:$s.height();s.cycleW=(opts.fit&&opts.width)?opts.width:$s.width();$s.css(opts.cssBefore);if(opts.pager||opts.pagerAnchorBuilder){$.fn.cycle.createPagerAnchor(els.length-1,s,$(opts.pager),els,opts);}if($.isFunction(opts.onAddSlide)){opts.onAddSlide($s);}else{$s.hide();}};}$.fn.cycle.resetState=function(opts,fx){fx=fx||opts.fx;opts.before=[];opts.after=[];opts.cssBefore=$.extend({},opts.original.cssBefore);opts.cssAfter=$.extend({},opts.original.cssAfter);opts.animIn=$.extend({},opts.original.animIn);opts.animOut=$.extend({},opts.original.animOut);opts.fxFn=null;$.each(opts.original.before,function(){opts.before.push(this);});$.each(opts.original.after,function(){opts.after.push(this);});var init=$.fn.cycle.transitions[fx];if($.isFunction(init)){init(opts.$cont,$(opts.elements),opts);}};function go(els,opts,manual,fwd){if(manual&&opts.busy&&opts.manualTrump){debug("manualTrump in go(), stopping active transition");$(els).stop(true,true);opts.busy=0;}if(opts.busy){debug("transition active, ignoring new tx request");return;}var p=opts.$cont[0],curr=els[opts.currSlide],next=els[opts.nextSlide];if(p.cycleStop!=opts.stopCount||p.cycleTimeout===0&&!manual){return;}if(!manual&&!p.cyclePause&&!opts.bounce&&((opts.autostop&&(--opts.countdown<=0))||(opts.nowrap&&!opts.random&&opts.nextSlide<opts.currSlide))){if(opts.end){opts.end(opts);}return;}var changed=false;if((manual||!p.cyclePause)&&(opts.nextSlide!=opts.currSlide)){changed=true;var fx=opts.fx;curr.cycleH=curr.cycleH||$(curr).height();curr.cycleW=curr.cycleW||$(curr).width();next.cycleH=next.cycleH||$(next).height();next.cycleW=next.cycleW||$(next).width();if(opts.multiFx){if(opts.lastFx==undefined||++opts.lastFx>=opts.fxs.length){opts.lastFx=0;}fx=opts.fxs[opts.lastFx];opts.currFx=fx;}if(opts.oneTimeFx){fx=opts.oneTimeFx;opts.oneTimeFx=null;}$.fn.cycle.resetState(opts,fx);if(opts.before.length){$.each(opts.before,function(i,o){if(p.cycleStop!=opts.stopCount){return;}o.apply(next,[curr,next,opts,fwd]);});}var after=function(){opts.busy=0;$.each(opts.after,function(i,o){if(p.cycleStop!=opts.stopCount){return;}o.apply(next,[curr,next,opts,fwd]);});};debug("tx firing("+fx+"); currSlide: "+opts.currSlide+"; nextSlide: "+opts.nextSlide);opts.busy=1;if(opts.fxFn){opts.fxFn(curr,next,opts,after,fwd,manual&&opts.fastOnEvent);}else{if($.isFunction($.fn.cycle[opts.fx])){$.fn.cycle[opts.fx](curr,next,opts,after,fwd,manual&&opts.fastOnEvent);}else{$.fn.cycle.custom(curr,next,opts,after,fwd,manual&&opts.fastOnEvent);}}}if(changed||opts.nextSlide==opts.currSlide){opts.lastSlide=opts.currSlide;if(opts.random){opts.currSlide=opts.nextSlide;if(++opts.randomIndex==els.length){opts.randomIndex=0;}opts.nextSlide=opts.randomMap[opts.randomIndex];if(opts.nextSlide==opts.currSlide){opts.nextSlide=(opts.currSlide==opts.slideCount-1)?0:opts.currSlide+1;}}else{if(opts.backwards){var roll=(opts.nextSlide-1)<0;if(roll&&opts.bounce){opts.backwards=!opts.backwards;opts.nextSlide=1;opts.currSlide=0;}else{opts.nextSlide=roll?(els.length-1):opts.nextSlide-1;opts.currSlide=roll?0:opts.nextSlide+1;}}else{var roll=(opts.nextSlide+1)==els.length;if(roll&&opts.bounce){opts.backwards=!opts.backwards;opts.nextSlide=els.length-2;opts.currSlide=els.length-1;}else{opts.nextSlide=roll?0:opts.nextSlide+1;opts.currSlide=roll?els.length-1:opts.nextSlide-1;}}}}if(changed&&opts.pager){opts.updateActivePagerLink(opts.pager,opts.currSlide,opts.activePagerClass);}var ms=0;if(opts.timeout&&!opts.continuous){ms=getTimeout(els[opts.currSlide],els[opts.nextSlide],opts,fwd);}else{if(opts.continuous&&p.cyclePause){ms=10;}}if(ms>0){p.cycleTimeout=setTimeout(function(){go(els,opts,0,!opts.backwards);},ms);}}$.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink=function(pager,currSlide,clsName){$(pager).each(function(){$(this).children().removeClass(clsName).eq(currSlide).addClass(clsName);});};function getTimeout(curr,next,opts,fwd){if(opts.timeoutFn){var t=opts.timeoutFn.call(curr,curr,next,opts,fwd);while(opts.fx!="none"&&(t-opts.speed)<250){t+=opts.speed;}debug("calculated timeout: "+t+"; speed: "+opts.speed);if(t!==false){return t;}}return opts.timeout;}$.fn.cycle.next=function(opts){advance(opts,1);};$.fn.cycle.prev=function(opts){advance(opts,0);};function advance(opts,moveForward){var val=moveForward?1:-1;var els=opts.elements;var p=opts.$cont[0],timeout=p.cycleTimeout;if(timeout){clearTimeout(timeout);p.cycleTimeout=0;}if(opts.random&&val<0){opts.randomIndex--;if(--opts.randomIndex==-2){opts.randomIndex=els.length-2;}else{if(opts.randomIndex==-1){opts.randomIndex=els.length-1;}}opts.nextSlide=opts.randomMap[opts.randomIndex];}else{if(opts.random){opts.nextSlide=opts.randomMap[opts.randomIndex];}else{opts.nextSlide=opts.currSlide+val;if(opts.nextSlide<0){if(opts.nowrap){return false;}opts.nextSlide=els.length-1;}else{if(opts.nextSlide>=els.length){if(opts.nowrap){return false;}opts.nextSlide=0;}}}}var cb=opts.onPrevNextEvent||opts.prevNextClick;if($.isFunction(cb)){cb(val>0,opts.nextSlide,els[opts.nextSlide]);}go(els,opts,1,moveForward);return false;}function buildPager(els,opts){var $p=$(opts.pager);$.each(els,function(i,o){$.fn.cycle.createPagerAnchor(i,o,$p,els,opts);});opts.updateActivePagerLink(opts.pager,opts.startingSlide,opts.activePagerClass);}$.fn.cycle.createPagerAnchor=function(i,el,$p,els,opts){var a;if($.isFunction(opts.pagerAnchorBuilder)){a=opts.pagerAnchorBuilder(i,el);debug("pagerAnchorBuilder("+i+", el) returned: "+a);}else{a='<a href="#">'+(i+1)+"</a>";}if(!a){return;}var $a=$(a);if($a.parents("body").length===0){var arr=[];if($p.length>1){$p.each(function(){var $clone=$a.clone(true);$(this).append($clone);arr.push($clone[0]);});$a=$(arr);}else{$a.appendTo($p);}}opts.pagerAnchors=opts.pagerAnchors||[];opts.pagerAnchors.push($a);$a.bind(opts.pagerEvent,function(e){e.preventDefault();opts.nextSlide=i;var p=opts.$cont[0],timeout=p.cycleTimeout;if(timeout){clearTimeout(timeout);p.cycleTimeout=0;}var cb=opts.onPagerEvent||opts.pagerClick;if($.isFunction(cb)){cb(opts.nextSlide,els[opts.nextSlide]);}go(els,opts,1,opts.currSlide<i);});if(!/^click/.test(opts.pagerEvent)&&!opts.allowPagerClickBubble){$a.bind("click.cycle",function(){return false;});}if(opts.pauseOnPagerHover){$a.hover(function(){opts.$cont[0].cyclePause++;},function(){opts.$cont[0].cyclePause--;});}};$.fn.cycle.hopsFromLast=function(opts,fwd){var hops,l=opts.lastSlide,c=opts.currSlide;if(fwd){hops=c>l?c-l:opts.slideCount-l;}else{hops=c<l?l-c:l+opts.slideCount-c;}return hops;};function clearTypeFix($slides){debug("applying clearType background-color hack");function hex(s){s=parseInt(s).toString(16);return s.length<2?"0"+s:s;}function getBg(e){for(;e&&e.nodeName.toLowerCase()!="html";e=e.parentNode){var v=$.css(e,"background-color");if(v&&v.indexOf("rgb")>=0){var rgb=v.match(/\d+/g);return"#"+hex(rgb[0])+hex(rgb[1])+hex(rgb[2]);}if(v&&v!="transparent"){return v;}}return"#ffffff";}$slides.each(function(){$(this).css("background-color",getBg(this));});}$.fn.cycle.commonReset=function(curr,next,opts,w,h,rev){$(opts.elements).not(curr).hide();if(typeof opts.cssBefore.opacity=="undefined"){opts.cssBefore.opacity=1;}opts.cssBefore.display="block";if(opts.slideResize&&w!==false&&next.cycleW>0){opts.cssBefore.width=next.cycleW;}if(opts.slideResize&&h!==false&&next.cycleH>0){opts.cssBefore.height=next.cycleH;}opts.cssAfter=opts.cssAfter||{};opts.cssAfter.display="none";$(curr).css("zIndex",opts.slideCount+(rev===true?1:0));$(next).css("zIndex",opts.slideCount+(rev===true?0:1));};$.fn.cycle.custom=function(curr,next,opts,cb,fwd,speedOverride){var $l=$(curr),$n=$(next);var speedIn=opts.speedIn,speedOut=opts.speedOut,easeIn=opts.easeIn,easeOut=opts.easeOut;$n.css(opts.cssBefore);if(speedOverride){if(typeof speedOverride=="number"){speedIn=speedOut=speedOverride;}else{speedIn=speedOut=1;}easeIn=easeOut=null;}var fn=function(){$n.animate(opts.animIn,speedIn,easeIn,function(){cb();});};$l.animate(opts.animOut,speedOut,easeOut,function(){$l.css(opts.cssAfter);if(!opts.sync){fn();}});if(opts.sync){fn();}};$.fn.cycle.transitions={fade:function($cont,$slides,opts){$slides.not(":eq("+opts.currSlide+")").css("opacity",0);opts.before.push(function(curr,next,opts){$.fn.cycle.commonReset(curr,next,opts);opts.cssBefore.opacity=0;});opts.animIn={opacity:1};opts.animOut={opacity:0};opts.cssBefore={top:0,left:0};}};$.fn.cycle.ver=function(){return ver;};$.fn.cycle.defaults={activePagerClass:"activeSlide",after:null,allowPagerClickBubble:false,animIn:null,animOut:null,autostop:0,autostopCount:0,backwards:false,before:null,cleartype:!$.support.opacity,cleartypeNoBg:false,containerResize:1,continuous:0,cssAfter:null,cssBefore:null,delay:0,easeIn:null,easeOut:null,easing:null,end:null,fastOnEvent:0,fit:0,fx:"fade",fxFn:null,height:"auto",manualTrump:true,next:null,nowrap:0,onPagerEvent:null,onPrevNextEvent:null,pager:null,pagerAnchorBuilder:null,pagerEvent:"click.cycle",pause:0,pauseOnPagerHover:0,prev:null,prevNextEvent:"click.cycle",random:0,randomizeEffects:1,requeueOnImageNotLoaded:true,requeueTimeout:250,rev:0,shuffle:null,slideExpr:null,slideResize:1,speed:1000,speedIn:null,speedOut:null,startingSlide:0,sync:1,timeout:4000,timeoutFn:null,updateActivePagerLink:null};})(jQuery);
```

[The concerned website.](http://www.oportunitas.es)
I just can't manage to find where would be the issue preventing this calendar to appear. Checked a few similar Qs, but no answer would be applicable to my issue. I'd appreciate some skilled insight! Thanks in advance, M.

Comment: Use the unminified version to get correct line of error.

Comment: I am not actually creating this code, it was already in my theme. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: have you included `wp_head` and `wp_footer` functions in your theme

Comment: `jquery.cycle.all.min.js` Filenames having `*.min.js` in them have been minified, in other words, compressed by removing extra spaces, comments and line breaks. You normally should have another file with the same name without the `min` part. Use this one to test your stuff.

Comment: Those are two different messages.  The TypeError is coming from line 176 of your page; the too few slides message is unrelated, and just for information

Comment: After trying to add this plug-in on any theme I could, I always get the same error. Could it be that it comes from a version compatibility? The [Demo website](http://www.dreamweaverdownloads.com/wpinstall/wordpress-3.4/) is on a 3.4, and I am using the 3.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was indeed from the plug-in code... 
I somehow ended up with a very old version of it, instead of using the latest one.
Thanks to all for your efforts, and sorry for wasting your time.